# SASS compound selector is causing an error

Tags: css, sass

I keep getting an error when compiling my SASS. I've checked the Sass documentation without any luck.

Here's my code:

```
    .tag {
        float:right;
        display: block;
        width: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        &-1 { background-color: saturate($borders, 10%); }
        &-2 { background-color: saturate($borders, 20%); }
        &-3 { background-color: saturate($borders, 30%); }
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
Invalid CSS after "         &": expected "{", was "_1 { background..."
"_1" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

I could manually code the css as .tag-1, .tag-2 and .tag-3 but this should work. What am I missing?

I'm racking my brain cause I can't see anything wrong with the syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work in SASS 3.3.

However, I question building class names dynamically like this. You might be better off using separate classes for the background color stuff:

```
&.bg1 { background-color: saturate($borders, 10%); }
&.bg2 { background-color: saturate($borders, 20%); }
&.bg3 { background-color: saturate($borders, 30%); }
```

That would add some better semantics to your HTML so people reading it could figure out what was going on:

```
<div class="tag bg2">
```

Comment: So what's the difference between what I am trying to do and the following from the Sass documentation:

#main {
  color: black;
  &-sidebar { border: 1px solid; }
}

Comment: @DaveOlson Your example will only output new classes. With your example you have base .tag OR .tag-1 (its not dry nor smart). His example is better because it has base (&) and modifier (what comes after &, e.g. &.modifier) classes (he has .tag AND .bg1, thus no need to repeat styles).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've modified my sass as suggested.